# How to Set admin Custom module Template file without Head and other Part in magento2

Tags: magento2

I just need to show my custom module template files on Magento 2 admin panel without any Magento 2 core JS and CSS and left menu section.

I can do the same things in Magento 1 custom module layout file using below code but the same alternate I have not found in magento2.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>Scanner/Main.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I have used the admin-empty layout but still its adding core JS and CSS file at head and also left menu which conflicting with my custom module JS and CSS file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>               
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Scanner\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Index" name="dsscanner_index" template="Namespace_Scanner::index.phtml"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I tired as per your suggestion but not working.